# AngularJs - consolidate 2 key-similar arrays into 1 ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have these 2 arrays of objects as below.

Array 1: Estimated Hours (`$scope.estimated_hours`)

```
[
  {
    "total_hours_spent_on_role": "56.00",
    "job_role": "Installing"
  },
  {
    "total_hours_spent_on_role": "46.00",
    "job_role": "Electrical"
  },
  {
    "total_hours_spent_on_role": "4.00",
    "job_role": "Delivery"
  },
  {
    "total_hours_spent_on_role": "2.00",
    "job_role": "Supervision"
  },
  {
    "total_hours_spent_on_role": "2.00",
    "job_role": "Commissioning"
  }
]
```

Array 2: Actual Hours (`$scope.actual_hours`)

```
[
  {
    "job_role": "Electrical",
    "total_hours_spent_on_role": "21.00"
  },
  {
    "job_role": "Installing",
    "total_hours_spent_on_role": "5.50"
  }
]
```

Now I want to use `ng-repeat` to output something similar to this, but haven't had any luck yet.

```
Installing: 5.50 (Act. Hours) / 56.00 (Est. Hours)

Electrical: 21.00 (Act. Hours) / 45.00 (Est. Hours)

Delivery: 0.00 (Act. Hours) / 4.00 (Est. Hours)

Supervision: 0.00 (Act. Hours) / 2.00 (Est. Hours)

Commissioning: 0.00 (Act. Hours) / 2.00 (Est. Hours)
```

How do we consolidate 2 arrays into 1 ng-repeat? I generally avoid using logic to merge them together.

Comment: you can use the $index in the ng-repeat to refer to the elements on the secondary array if they are the same length and they have a direct relation

Comment: I've seen array concatenation done by ng-repeat, haven't seen any logic to merge them though. Just as a thought, you could change your structure from having two arrays to one array within your controller such as `var hours { actual_hours: []; estimated_hours: []; job_role: String }`. This way you aren't storing job_role twice.

Comment: when roles are same, why not have it in same json from backend logic. Like mentioned above by @DavidLi

Comment: Those 2 objects are being queried very differently in the backend (server-side) model. But I can merge them together in the Angular's controller though, just thought ng-repeat can help in certain way :)

Comment: one way or the other merging is required, there is no direct option through ng-repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

```js
var arr1 = [{
    "total_hours_spent_on_role": "56.00",
    "job_role": "Installing"
  }, {
    "total_hours_spent_on_role": "46.00",
    "job_role": "Electrical"
  }, {
    "total_hours_spent_on_role": "4.00",
    "job_role": "Delivery"
  }, {
    "total_hours_spent_on_role": "2.00",
    "job_role": "Supervision"
  }, {
    "total_hours_spent_on_role": "2.00",
    "job_role": "Commissioning"
  }
];


var arr2 = [{
  "job_role": "Electrical",
  "total_hours_spent_on_role": "21.00"
}, {
  "job_role": "Installing",
  "total_hours_spent_on_role": "5.50"
}];

var app = angular.module("myapp", [])

.controller("arrCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.arr = arr1;
    $scope.getArr2ValByKey = function(key) {
      var val = arr2.filter(function(i) {

        return i.job_role == key.job_role;
      }).map(function(a) {
        console.log(a);
        return a.total_hours_spent_on_role;
      })[0];
      return val || 0.0;
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="arrCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="a in arr">{{a.job_role}} : (Act hours){{getArr2ValByKey(a)}} / {{a.total_hours_spent_on_role}} (Act hours)</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks neat :) Thanks mate.